# Returning SCOPE_IDENTITY() using Adodb.Command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado

I have an Insert statement (Stored Procedure) that returns the SCOPE_IDENTITY() after insert, however, I am trying to figure out how to return it after I use an `ADODB.Command` request in Classic ASP.

The SP has this included at the end:

```
SET @LastID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- @LastID is an INT OUTPUT param.
```

This is what is called when processing an Insert query in classic ASP code:

```
set SQLCOMM = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
SQLCOMM.ActiveConnection = CONNSTRING
SQLCOMM.CommandText = "Insert_SP_Returns_ScopeID"
SQLCOMM.CommandType = 1
SQLCOMM.CommandTimeout = 0
SQLCOMM.Prepared = true

LastIDParameter = SQLCOMM.CreateParameter("@LastID",adInteger,adParamOutput)
SQLCOMM.Parameters.Add(LastIDParameter)

SQLCOMM.Execute() 

LastID = LastIDParameter.Value

set SQLCOMM=Nothing
```

Do I just do something like this before i `set SQLCOMM=Nothing` ?

```
NewID = SQLCOMM("LastID").Value
```

OR... can an Insert/Update Stored Procedure be executed from a `Adodb.Recordset` instead of `ADODB.Command` instead?

```
    The example above gives the following error message:
    ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'

    Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, 
    or are in conflict with one another.
```

The error is being returned due to this line of code:

```
LastIDParameter = SQLCOMM.CreateParameter("@LastID",adInteger,adParamOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command approach to calling the stored procedure is fine.  All you have to do is add an extra output parameter to the command object.  (I havent done any vbscript for years and so i am not sure whether you should be explicitly type your variables).

In VB script

```
set SQLCOMM = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
SQLCOMM.ActiveConnection = CONNSTRING 
SQLCOMM.CommandText = "Insert_SP_Returns_ScopeID" 
SQLCOMM.CommandType = 1 
SQLCOMM.CommandTimeout = 0 
SQLCOMM.Prepared = true 

Dim LastIDParameter
Dim LastID

LastIDParameter = SQLCOMM.CreateParameter("@LastID",adInteger,adParamOutput)
SQLCOMM.Parameters.Add(LastIDParameter)

SQLCOMM.Execute() 

LastID = LastIDParameter.Value

set SQLCOMM=Nothing
```

And then in your stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_SP_Returns_ScopeID

@Value1 int,
@Value2 int,
@LastID int OUTPUT

AS

INSERT INTO TableName(Value1,Value2) VALUES (@Value1,@Value2)

SET @LastID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

EDIT: You might need to look up the values of adInteger,adParamOutput and use those as the constants may not be defined for your environment. If so use...

```
SQLCOMM.CreateParameter("@LastID",3,2)
```

or define the constants.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting an error on this:

ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9' 
Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another. 

LINE CAUSING THE ERROR:
LastIDParameter = SQLCOMM.CreateParameter("@LastID",adInteger,adParamOutput)