# error '800a01b6': Object doesn't support this property or method: Object.Parameters.Add'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado

This is an extension to:
[Returning SCOPE_IDENTITY() using Adodb.Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238486/returning-scope-identity-using-adodb-command)

Trying to get SCOPE_IDENTITY() using ADO.Command from a SP but get an error when I run the Ado.Command.. Here is the code example:

The Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTSP
@LASTID int OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO TABLE1 (VAL1,VAL2) VALUES (VAL1,VAL2)

SET @LASTID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

The ADO Request:

```
set SQLCOMM = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
SQLCOMM.ActiveConnection = CONNSTRING
SQLCOMM.CommandText = TESTSP
SQLCOMM.CommandType = 1
SQLCOMM.CommandTimeout = 0
SQLCOMM.Prepared = true

LastIDParameter = SQLCOMM.CreateParameter("@LastID",3,2)
SQLCOMM.Parameters.Add(LastIDParameter) 

SQLCOMM.Execute()

INSERT_RETURNS_SCOPEID=LastIDParameter.Value

set SQLCOMM=Nothing
```

This is causing the error: `LastIDParameter = SQLCOMM.CreateParameter("@LastID",3,2)`

Comment: Since you are using a SP I guess that command type should be 4. `SQLCOMM.CommandType = 4`. Don't know if that will take care of your problem.

Comment: Did my answer resolve your error?

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

```
SQLCOMM.CommandType = 1
```

should be instead:

```
SQLCOMM.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```